# Why does the TypeScript compiler compiles enums to functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, language-design

## TL;DR

The Typescript compiler compiles enums to functions, and it does so in a seemingly peculiar way. What are the benefits?

**Note:**

1. **This question is not opinion-based**. I am looking for *objective, verifiable* ways in which the compiled JavaScript code is better than the trivial option. I am not asking about the thinking process of the designers -- we cannot read their minds.
2. **This question is not a duplicate**. At least not a duplicate of the following two questions:

   - [Compile an enum in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871129/compile-an-enum-in-typescript) - This question is asking *what* is the compiled JavaScript, not *why* it is compiled that way.
   - [Why does the TypeScript transpiler compile enums into dictionary lookups instead of simple objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929362/why-does-the-typescript-transpiler-compile-enums-into-dictionary-lookups-instead) - This question is specifically asking about the following expression: `Enum[Enum["None"] = 0] = "None"`, while my question is about the *function* aspects of the compiled code.

---

## And now in detail

Suppose I define the following enum in TypeScript:

```
enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

This compiles to the following IIFE:

```
var Color;
(function (Color) {
    Color[Color["Red"] = 0] = "Red";
    Color[Color["Green"] = 1] = "Green";
    Color[Color["Blue"] = 2] = "Blue";
})(Color || (Color = {}));
```

Why do we need the IIFE? Furthermore, since `Color` is presumably *known* to be `undefined`, and hence falsy, `Color || (Color = {})` is seemingly *guaranteed* to be evaluated to `Color = {}`. So what is the point of this expression?

I would presume an equivalent yet simpler implementation would look something like this:

```
var Color = {}; // why not let?
Color[Color["Red"] = 0] = "Red";
Color[Color["Green"] = 1] = "Green";
Color[Color["Blue"] = 2] = "Blue";
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Add `enum Color { Purple = 4 }` in the same TS file. What happens? What it compiles to? What does the compiled object look like?

Comment: Note: `var Color;` doesn’t overwrite `Color` if it already exists in the same scope, so `Color || (Color = {})` isn’t strictly redundant after it.

Comment: Any transpiler is going to follow some reliable translation strategies. Your question is asking why the Typscript implementors chose the approach that they chose. It certainly works; perhaps there are other language constructs for which that scheme would be more obviously advantageous, and they simply re-used an existing pattern. Ultimately, it's the Typescript maintainers what would have the best answers to this question.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks. I am not sure what you mean. If it already exists in the same scope, wouldn't I get an `Identifier 'Color' has already been declared` error?

Comment: TS supports [namespace merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces), which includes the namespace generated in an enum declaration.  Does [this example](https://tsplay.dev/WYL3vm) explain what's going on to you?  If so I could write up a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - I did not know that a namespace would be compiled to practically the same code as an enum. I am not sure why this behavior (pretty new to TS). It will be great if you could elaborate, perhaps in an answer.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A TypeScript `enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) declaration creates the equivalent of a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) that holds both the enum members, as well as the types of these members.  Your `Color` enum is quite similar to the following:

```
namespace Color {
  export const Red = 0;
  export type Red = typeof Red;  
  export const Green = 1;
  export type Green = typeof Green;
  export const Blue = 2;
  export type Blue = typeof Blue;  
}
type Color = typeof Color[keyof typeof Color];
```

(although the above doesn't provide [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings); these can also be emulated but to do so would be too much of a digression here.)

---

Furthermore, TypeScript supports [namespace merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces), where multiple [`namespace`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#handbook-content) of the same name are *combined*.   A namespace is "open" in this sense:

```
namespace Foo {
  export const x = "abc";
}

namespace Foo {
  export const y = Math.PI;
}

console.log(
  Foo.x.toUpperCase(), Foo.y.toFixed(2)
); // "ABC", "3.14"
```

That means you can also merge enums:

```
enum Bar {
  x = 1
}

enum Bar {
  y = 2
}
```

or even merge `namespace`s and `enum`s together:

```
namespace Bar {
  export function f() { console.log(Bar.x, Bar.y) }
}

Bar.f(); // 1, 2
```

---

In order for that to work in JavaScript, it means that a variable with the name of the namespace/enum must exist, but if it already exists you just want to modify it and not replace it.  That means you don't want to *assign* anything to it at all.  Hence output like:

```
var Bar;

(function (Bar) {
    Bar[Bar["x"] = 1] = "x";
})(Bar || (Bar = {}));

(function (Bar) {
    Bar[Bar["y"] = 2] = "y";
})(Bar || (Bar = {}));

(function (Bar) {
    function f() { console.log(Bar.x, Bar.y); }
    Bar.f = f;
})(Bar || (Bar = {}));
```

Each block will use an existing `Bar` value if it is already defined, otherwise it will assign a fresh empty object to `Bar` and use that instead.  The IIFE is presumably for scoping, to keep unexported namespace variables private (including `var` delcarations so [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) wouldn't be appropriate either, even if your target runtime supports it).

---

So there you go; an `enum` is implemented as a `namespace` and `namespace`s can be merged, so you get IIFEs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgJWAEwBosoBxZYUY7AIQTGAwF8MMQBDCYAZwAd2AxsCgBlAJYQxCdqkwkOXPoOHwksktmAAPXigAuUAXBDcDefFAC8UAAwBuDVG27kBvQE9ew81agevcABmuAQO2Jo6+obGpmQUoL4AjGHhzlH+wuSUIL4ZQXHZKREuBkYmBnQMvgBMRU6Rrn6ewpXC1nnBrSks2BmwiCi5zfmqKADaANbA7vkd-WoAug4sbJw8-EJQAJIgAvT4wHgAbsDI3MAAsuy8vGIgAOboJGWxo6jWmOEh+ABcttThLKgP6JAG0ejAP7VMFQMY2BZ-ABE5kRMLGiQRUERQJAqMcY2qmMRrURJCYUHY3Gi5RSCnWynmg0+qQabma3yGAWCbwAdOY6mlGn0cZzgCMBsgeTiBayml4oK1ReK1DyumSSH03kruRLJtNZsMdYsHMxWHSlJsAGJwOBPYpRF4GLS+RHsABGAkRyzNawtwmttuZgtKMQM7l8Vz0AAseQAFLbejAvRDAHlIe4AChIAZ5Wh5ejgAFUbqcYJTgBmAJSEKA59z5uCWsRaAgZ6qVjCVuxQAD0PaxAEEaDBUViAMw8xIAFlJGFAkAVMjtUGd1kSprn4GgNCXzPD1mqG-NGxau5IwaggTAuz0YmMl6r6Gp3BTabgmZ3kq0Nc-PPclagFgVl-QIq27PsoFBKBqiAA)